# Joint distribution from a continuous conditional and discrete marginal

Tags: conditional-probability, statistical-inference, maximum-likelihood

So I'm struggling to find the joint distribution of an (X,Y) bivariate population where X is discrete 0, 1 and 2 with equal probabilities and the conditional distribution of Y
given X = x is exponential with mean $\beta(x + 1)$ with  $\beta > 0$.

I know that

$$f_{x,y}(x,y) =f(y \mid x)*f_{x}(x)$$

But in this case, I'm not sure how to compute that product

(The exercise is actually about computing an ML estimator for $\beta$, but I can't even begin without having the joint distribution since my sample is from the bivariate population)

Comment: Discrete r.v. 's don't even have densities.

Comment: You are right, they have probability mass functions (pmf), I just wrote like density to simplify

Comment: The product seems simple (though it is neither a probability nor a density):  $\frac1{3\beta(x+1)}e^{-y/(\beta(x+1))}$ when $x \in \{0,1,2\}$ and $y \ge 0$.  And the likelihood is proportional to this product, and to the slightly simpler $\frac1{x+1}e^{-y/(\beta(x+1))}$ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking about joint distribution when one of the RVs is discrete is not correct, but you could compute the pmf of it by taking the derivative of the cdf. If $x$ has a discrete distribution on $[0,1,2]$ with equal probabilities and $Y|X=x \sim Exp(\beta(x+1))$ then the cdf will be

$$P(X=x,Y\leq y)=\frac{1}{3}\left(1-e^{\left(\beta(1+x)\right)^{-1}y}\right)$$

So taking the derivative
$$f(x,y)= \frac{1}{3}\left(\beta\left(1+x\right)\right)^{-1}exp\left(-\left(\beta\left(1+x\right)\right)^{-1}y\right)$$

If you want to find the MLE of $\beta$, first the likelihood will be
(dropping out terms that do not depend on $\beta$):

$$\mathcal{L} \propto \beta^{-n}exp\left(-\frac{1}{\beta}\left(n_{0}\bar{y}_{0} + \frac{1}{2}n_{1}\bar{y}_{1} + \frac{1}{3}n_{2}\bar{y}_{2}\right)\right)$$

where $\bar{y}_{i}$ is the conditional mean of $y$ conditional on $x=i$ and $n_{i}$ the sample size. Log likelihood:

$$\log\mathcal{L} \propto -n\log \beta -\frac{1}{\beta}\left(n_{0}\bar{y}_{0} + \frac{1}{2}n_{1}\bar{y}_{1} + \frac{1}{3}n_{2}\bar{y}_{2}\right)$$

First order condition yields
$$\frac{n}{\beta} = \frac{1}{\beta^{2}}\left(n_{0}\bar{y}_{0} + \frac{1}{2}n_{1}\bar{y}_{1} + \frac{1}{3}n_{2}\bar{y}_{2}\right)$$

And therefore

$$\beta^{MLE}=\frac{n_{0}\bar{y}_{0} + \frac{1}{2}n_{1}\bar{y}_{1} + \frac{1}{3}n_{2}\bar{y}_{2}}{n}$$

Comment: Thanks!
To know if I understand correctly, the sum inside the exponential in the likelihood comes from the fact that some of the elements of the sample come from the x=1, some from the x=2, and some from the x=3 right?
And one can't add those y's together because each of those y's comes from a different "distribution"...right?

Comment: Exactly! But then you can rewrite it in that way to avoid dealing with funky denominators

Comment: Great then! Thank you very much